# Give IDs to variation on gaps and islands problem

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, partition, gaps-and-islands

This dataset contains one ordered timestamp column (`A`) along with a pair of marker columns (`B + C`) that represent the start and end of a '**block**', what I'm looking to produce is (`D`).

I've had a hard time of explaining this problem to colleagues, but essentially I need a way of giving an `ID` to these blocks of varying row count but note that on row 8 as an example a block can sometimes only occupy one row.

```
|           A         |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-----------------------------------------
| 06/10/2018 13:17:40 |  1  |  0  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:17:56 |  0  |  0  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:08 |  0  |  1  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:21 |  1  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:26 |  0  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:26 |  0  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:28 |  0  |  1  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:28 |  1  |  1  |  3  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:31 |  1  |  0  |  4  |
| 06/10/2018 19:49:26 |  0  |  0  |  4  |
| 06/10/2018 19:50:24 |  0  |  1  |  4  |
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want, could u please add "expected output" to your question

Comment: Hint for you:- LAG()

Comment: Sorry I meant to explain that column D here in the example table is what I want to output, I'm interested if there is an alternative method to just using partitioned lag/lead functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `LAG` window function in subquery then use `SUM` window function with condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT A,B,C,SUM(CASE WHEN preC = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY A,preC) +1  'D'
FROM (
 SELECT *,
        LAG(C,1,C) OVER(ORDER BY A) preC
 FROM T 
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d541468b72e7be05ca29c03ce908049f)

**Result**

```
|           A         |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-----------------------------------------
| 06/10/2018 13:17:40 |  1  |  0  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:17:56 |  0  |  0  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:08 |  0  |  1  |  1  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:21 |  1  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:26 |  0  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:26 |  0  |  0  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:28 |  0  |  1  |  2  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:28 |  1  |  1  |  3  |
| 06/10/2018 13:18:31 |  1  |  0  |  4  |
| 06/10/2018 19:49:26 |  0  |  0  |  4  |
| 06/10/2018 19:50:24 |  0  |  1  |  4  |
```

Comment: No problem glad to help you can accept this question if that help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what `C` has to do with the problem.  This is just a cumulative sum on `B`:

```
select a, b, c,
       sum(b) over (order by a) as d
from t;
```